# Is there a way to randomize GRUB2 boot loader background?

Tags: boot, grub2

Is it possible to select a random background for [GRUB2](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) during boot-up from a folder? I tried to add a small script to the `/etc/default/grub` file but it must be updated manually to select a random background. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a shutdown/reboot script so that when you switch to the relevant run level the script gets run?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/175486/is-reboot-the-same-as-init-6
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64280/what-is-the-difference-between-reboot-init-6-and-shutdown-r-now

This way the script basically gets run automatically (but manually) allowing you to change background on each boot?

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/grub-splash-image/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/115432/change-boot-entry-names-and-grub-background

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am new to Linux and tinkering with the boot process scares me!